# Adding support for different languages in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySql version is `5.0.51b-community-nt`.

Right now, I have `Character set` as `latin1` and `Collation` as `latin_swedish_ci` for database, all the tables and all the `varchar` columns in those tables.

Now I need to add support for other languages too. So I guess setting `Character set` as `utf8` and `collation` as `utf8_unicode_ci` for all the `varchar` columns of all the tables would be sufficient. Or do I have to change these at tables and database level too?

Also, would it affect my existing data?

Also will database size grow? and how it will affect queries while joining or searching?

Comment: IIRC all new tables will inherit this but you will need to go around and change the existing ones manualy. Not postet as an answer as i might be totaly wrong, not used MySQL in ages.